# Magento: Delaying Head Block from loading until my event has fired

Tags: magento, events, block, observers, load-order

I have two observers:

```
<events>
    <controller_action_layout_load_before>
      <observers>
        <QuBit_UniversalVariable_Model_Page_Observer>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>universal_variable_main/observer</class>
          <method>setUniversalVariable</method>
        </QuBit_UniversalVariable_Model_Page_Observer>
      </observers>
    </controller_action_layout_load_before>
    <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
      <observers>
        <QuBit_UniversalVariable_Model_Page_Observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>universal_variable_main/observer</class>
            <method>setCatalogProductListing</method>
        </QuBit_UniversalVariable_Model_Page_Observer>
      </observers>
    </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
  </events>
```

I want a **Block** containing javascript to load in my Head, but need to populate it with data that is collected in an **Observer**. My problem is that the block loads before the event fires. I added some logging to prove this.

```
2013-07-12T07:18:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): loading setUniversalVariable
2013-07-12T07:18:44+00:00 DEBUG (7): loading template
2013-07-12T07:18:48+00:00 DEBUG (7): loading setCatalogProductListing
```

At the moment I am adding the block using layout XML, do I need to instead create it programmatically in *setCatalogProductListing* or is there some other way of prevent it from being loaded until all the data is available?

And is it even possible to create it programmatically here or will the head already have been finalised by this point?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, the head will already have been output, as the `catalog_block_product_list_collection` event is fired in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::_beforeToHtml()` (so, when the products list is being rendered). Do you really need to populate your script in the head ?

Comment: Yes as its a Universal-Variable javascript object that the QuBit Opentag tag management scripts will call. These can be injected anywhere in the DOM, secondly I want to do a pull request on the git project so that it gets merged with the main repoistory so it should work properly in all scenarios.

When you say that the head will already have been output, do you mean that even programmatically adding a block will fail? I'm a bit confused by the "Yes" you started your comment with.

Comment: Further to above, do blocks render into a buffer that is then sent when the whole page has been built, or are they sent as output as they are rendered. If they are rendered into a buffer, is there a way to grab this buffer to manipulate it as a string?

Comment: Edit: OK having read [link](http://alanstorm.com/magento_listener_lifecycle_block) Alans excellent post on the block life cycle I think I now understand what is going on and @blmage I believe your comment is actually an answer - the event can never get to the Head block as it has actually rendered. If you want to paste your comment into an answer, I'll except it.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer ! By "Yes", I meant that at the time the event is dispatched, the head is already output so nothing can actually alter it, even if you add a block in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time the `catalog_block_product_list_collection` event is dispatched, the `head` has already been output, so nothing can actually alter it (or in fact, it depends on where the list block is placed, but in almost all cases it will be after the head).

You would have to deal directly with the layout and list blocks to retrieve data from the collection before the head is rendered, but the ways of doing depend on whether you want to apply your code on all list blocks or, eg, just category ones (knowing that blocks can also be called from CMS contents, and therefore may not exist before the corresponding page / block is itself output).